# Access 2010 format property date/time Long Date

Tags: format, ms-access-2010

When you set the format property for a Date/Time field in a table to a Long Date, switch to Datasheet view, then click inside the Date/Time field, the format does not disappear anymore as in older versions of Access. You cannot edit the date since you do not see the original data.
Here is what I have: Date value: 11/26/2012
Long Date format: Monday, November 26, 2012
Field receive focus: Monday, November 26, 2012

When you are in Datasheet view, select the field (click inside), the format remains. In Access 2003 (under Win XP), the format disappears and the value 11/26/2012 is displayed. I have just verified this today. For text and number fields, the format goes away when the field receive focus.

When you add a time component other than midnight(00:00) than it works as expected:
Date value: 11/26/2012 01:00
Long Date format: Monday, November 26, 2012
Field receive focus: 11/26/2012 01:00

It seems that this is a bug of some sort, unless I am missing something here. May be it has to do with the Date Picker control (I turned it on and off, no change in behavior).

Access 2010 runs under Win 7, Access 2003 runs under Win XP.

Could anyone confirm this behavior and/or provide more guidance on how to handle this?

Thanks,